# Error on Access database after changes were made

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know this is a long shot, but I really need help and I am new to Microsoft Access and working on some legacy code and I can't figure out what the problem is.

As with every other Access db, I have some tables, columns, queries, reports etc.

After a co-worker changed the name of some tables (possibly added/deleted columns too etc.), this code stopped working. It's a simple SQL statement, that queries against `tabel1` and inserts the information in a form. Notice the database worked perfectly before the person changing it.

**Code that doesn't Work anymore and highlight of where the error happens:**

[image]

(I have added the code in bottom, but leaving the picture to highlight where the error occurs)

**Error im receiving:**

Run-time error '2580': Record Source does not exist

*Question: If record source does not exist, what is it that actually dont exist?*

---

**My thoughts on the error**

My SQL obviously exists, so I assume that `subAvoidPrivatList` is the problem? **Is this a list I can access in design/layout view?** (would like to take your guesses on it, since I can find the list anywhere) Or what would your guess be?  Or can the error be triggered, because some of the tables/columns doesn't exist anymore?

Any help appreciated

**EDIT: Added code-version of picture above**

```
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT tabel1.area, tabel1.[are systemname], tabel1.[charge name] // +15 columns that im gonna leave out for brevity
    & "FROM tabel1 " _
    & "WHERE [charge name] LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' " _
    & " AND [avoid] = '" & Me.avoidcheck & "' " _
    & " AND [area systemname] LIKE '*" & Me.test1 & "*' " _
    & " AND [area] LIKE '*" & Me.resub & "*' " _
    & "ORDER BY tabel1.[Id] "

Me.subAvoidPrivatList.Form.RecordSource = SQL
Me.subAvoidPrivatList.Form.Requery
```

Comment: Please provide your past and current code - as text, not a cropped picture.

Comment: @Gustav Added code to bottom of post. I remind you once again that the code worked perfectly before an employee made changes to the database table, which indicates that the code is not the problem. Highligted line is where error happens.

Comment: Well, then provide the changes of the table schema.

Comment: @Gustav The co-worker didn't document changes and made several.  Code worked perfectly before changes were made. As mentioned in bottom of my post, I am asking if updating the database (changing names, deleting columns etc.) can trigger this error.

Comment: What can we know? We don't even have the current schema. Seems like your co-worker needs some education and - most important - owe you a large beer.

Comment: @Gustav Yeah, I figured it was a really long shot and a pretty much impossible question to answer without more insights. I guess I was fishing for hints on how error 2580 is normally triggered, e.g. whether it can be caused by changing the tables/columns or if it is more likely triggered because `subAvoidPrivatList` has been deleted or something. Thanks for looking a bit into it at least, and I agree with you on that last part about beer ;-)

Comment: One thing I would try is to put a stop on the line ME.subAvoidPrivatList.Form.RecordSource = SQL, step into the code, and then start typing a new line of code above it starting with "Me." A drop-down list will appear after you type the period which may help you determine whether or not subAvoidPrivatList has been deleted.

Comment: Also, in your VBE do you see anything related to AvoidPrivatList in your list of Access Class Objects in the project pane. Put a stop at the beginning of it so you can stop the code from automatically running through it.

Comment: @MBB70 Thank you for the suggestions, I am in transportation at the moment and will follow up at next chance by my computer

Comment: Paste your SQL into a new query, this will get you better error messages. [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because your SQL statement doesn't match the structure of your table.  To solve this, you will either need to fix the SQL or try to figure out how to put `tabel1` back the way it was.

To fix the SQL, make sure to ONLY use columns which are (currently) in `tabel1` (after the recent changes). Of course, this might break other stuff in your MS Access forms or reports.

Fixing the table is much more difficult, but possible if you have enough determination. Start by looking at which columns are being used in your query, but are missing in the table.  You will need to guess at what type they used to be.  Add those into your table. Expect some trial and error, of course.

From the query that you've posted, I would expect `tabel1` to contain (at least) the following columns:

```
Id,
area, 
[are systemname],  //possibly you misspelled this column in your SELECT clause
[area systemname], //this is probably the correct spelling
[charge name],
avoid,
//and you omitted the other columns, but you get the idea
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I am in transportation at the moment and will follow up at next chance by my computer

Answer (score 1):

okay so " a co-worker changed the name of some tables (possibly added/deleted columns too etc.)," ….this is the worst possible idea I have every seen.  Tables are the foundation of the structure and changing the foundation after the structure is built is a promise of many headaches.

the advice you've been already given of updating your queries to meet the new table structure is correct....though there can still be a lot of problems above the query in the presentation level (forms/reports) which will throw errors until they get adapted as well.

depending on the quantity of changes you might seriously consider returning to the version before the coworker did the damage....